# Disabling the snapping-grid in fabricjs

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I managed to snap the objects to grid using round-off.

```
canvas.on('object:moving', function(options) {
    options.target.set({
        left: Math.round(options.target.left / grid) * grid,
        top: Math.round(options.target.top / grid) * grid
    });
});
```

How do I disable this, say, on button click?

I tried using a flag isGridEnabled and doing:

```
canvas.on('object:moving', function(options) {
    options.target.set({
        left: options.target.left,
        top: options.target.top 
    });
});
```

but the object(s) still snap to grid!

Answer (score 1):

Use `.off` to remove an event handler from a Fabric canvas.

I'll quote what kangax (the creator of Fabric.js) posted in a comment to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18737058/3345375):

```
function f(opts) {
    eventHandler(opts, arg1, arg2)
}
canvas.on('object:over', f);
canvas.off('object:over', f);
```

([Official docs](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Observable.html#off) and [related Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34077391/3345375).)

Then just add an event listener to a button or other element.

```
el.addEventListener('click', function(){
    canvas.off('object:over', f);
});
```

In your case, you might refactor your code this way:

```
function activateGrid(options) {
    options.target.set({
        left: Math.round(options.target.left / grid) * grid,
        top: Math.round(options.target.top / grid) * grid
    });
}

onButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    canvas.on('object:moving', activateGrid);
});

offButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    canvas.off('object:moving', activateGrid);
});
```

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this question?

Comment: I did indeed. [And what a fine answer it is!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38605156/3345375)

Comment: i assume you used the one provided here, but you never accepted the answer. you have seen my question, i used a checkbox and want to turn it off when the checkbox is unchecked. how do i do that or do you have a working fiddle so i can look at the full thing ( i visualise it better)

Comment: As I understand it, a user only gets a notification of your comment (1) if you comment on that user's post directly, or (2) if you put an @ symbol before the username. Since you didn't comment on  Mohit Chawla's question, he probably hasn't seen your comment.