# how to turn off snap to grid fabricjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I have a checkbox that i want to enable to turn on and off `Snap2grid` in `fabric js`. Now I can turn it on ok, but how do I turn it off [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wayneker/797z1oby/1/)

```
$('#on-off-switch').change(function() {
    var $check = $(this),
        $div = $check.parent();

    if ($check.prop('checked')) {
        // Turn On Snap2Grid 
        canvas.on('object:moving', function(options) {
            options.target.set({
                left: Math.round(options.target.left / grid) * grid,
                top: Math.round(options.target.top / grid) * grid
            });
        });
        $("#on-off-label").text("On");
    } else {
        // Turn Off Snap2Grid
        $("#on-off-label").text("Off");
    }
});
```

Comment: Related question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34751006/3345375

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is a very large JSFiddle and I think you might have other issues in your code.

There a few ways to have different behavior one is to check some global propery in the event function itself:

```
canvas.on('object:moving', function(event) {
  if(window.snapTo) {
        event.target.set({
            left: Math.round(options.target.left / grid) * grid,
            top: Math.round(options.target.top / grid) * grid
        });
  } else {
    // do nothing
  }
})
```

another way is to just remove the event.

You can remove all events like this:

```
canvas.off();
```

Or all events of a type:

```
canvas.off('object:moving');
```

Or if you have a reference to the function just the single bound event handler:

```
canvas.off('object:moving', eventHandlerFunction);
```

Comment: i understand its a big fabricjs, i have asked in a previous question but no answers how to add multiple instances of the same Rect. but ty for this answer. I thought i tried the canvas.off('object:moving'); but i musnt have as this worked.

Comment: you can't add the exact same rect multiple times but you can `.clone()` to get an exact copy.

Comment: Thank you Stefan. This had me so confused. I'm still a little puzzled. My function name is gridOff(). So I have tried: canvas.off('object:moving', gridOff); This doesn't work for me, but canvas.off('object:moving'); does work. I think my problem is syntax. I'm not a good coder, but trying. Thanks again for your answer. -Rachel